# css margins not displaying divs in correct places

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
html,body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.box {
    width:475px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 20px 0 auto;
    padding:12px;
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height:60px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
.box h2 {
    font-size:44px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.box p {
    font-size:60px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

but the divs with the two lines of text in make the values/numbers display lower than all the other divs with only one line of text.

how can i make all the

values/numbers display in the same place inside the the `.box` divs?

Here is a fiddle with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/8kex9/

Comment: Either give a fixed height to `.box h2`.  Or, remove the fixed height from `.box`, but I assume you want them all the same height.

Comment: just removed that here - http://jsfiddle.net/8kex9/1/ - but it now shows the .box divs different heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you could do something like this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kex9/2/)

Giving them both absolute positions, will cause them to be positioned based on parent, rather than the sibling. You just can't add too many lines of text, or else it will run into each other.

```
.box h2 {
    font-size:44px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 465px;
}
.box p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:60px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 465px;
}
```

Comment: perfect thank you... i have removed the float:left property on the .box div which makes the divs display in the centre but can i make the bottom two display underneath the two above? (make the screen size so there are 3 divs across) rather than the two divs displaying in the centre of the 3 above?

Comment: That's a lot of words haha. I don't follow.  You  may want to make that a new question and resolve this one (two different issues)

Comment: ok, new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717974/make-css-divs-display-directly-underneath-divs-above and your answer has been ticked :)